# Why does this falsely lead to $g_{\mu \nu}$ always being the identity map?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, notation

[So I posted a question about the tetrad basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4486287/) but later realised that there is a more fundamental, underlying question that is better suited here.

I’m using abstract index notation to denote all tensors, meaning that all Latin indices are symbolic references to slots and all Greek indices are references to specific components in a specified basis. Tensor products are written as two tensors next to each other, for example: $T^{ab} = v^a w^b$, and contractions are written by repeating indices, for instance $R_{ab} = R_{acb}^c$.

Essentially, given a metric tensor $g = g_{ab}$ and its inverse tensor $g^{-1} = g^{ab}$, the compound tensor $g_a^b = g_{ac} g^{cb}$ that you get from inserting one metric into either slots of the second one is said to be the identity map:

$$
g_a^b = g_{ac} g^{cb} = \delta_a^b.\tag{1}
$$

In practice, this means that $g^b_a$ applied to any tensor just changes the name of the slot from $a$ to $b$ or the other way around (i.e. it “does nothing”). The components are of course given by:

$$
g_\mu^\nu = g_{\mu \sigma} g^{\sigma \nu}.\tag{2}
$$

So the components $g^\nu_\mu$ in any basis may differ from the components $g_{\mu \nu}$.

But we also have, from inserting the basis vectors into the tensor to get its tensor components:

$$
g_{\mu \nu} = g_{ab} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)^a \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}\right) ^b = (dx^\mu )_a \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}  \right)^a = \delta_\nu^\mu\tag{3}
$$

where we have used that $g_{ab} T^a = T_b$ for any tensor, and hence also for basis vectors $T^a = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right)^a$. Moreover, I assumed that lowering an index for a basis vector yields its corresponding dual vector, where “corresponding” is tested via the condition $$(dx^\mu )_a \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}  \right)^a \equiv dx^\mu \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}  \right) = \delta^\mu_\nu .\tag{4}$$

As you can see, here is the problem. First of all, why do I end up with mixed indices on either sides of the equation? Secondly, why do I get that the components of the metric in any basis is the identity map?

Comment: (a) All the equation $g_{ac}g^{cb}=\delta^b_a$ is saying is that $g g^{-1}=1$. (b) It is totally unclear to me what is going on in your last equation. What is $(\partial/\partial x^\mu)^a$? How did you go from $(\partial/\partial x^\mu)^a$ to $(dx^\mu)_a$? Of course this step is why you go from a lower $\mu$ index to an upper $\mu$ index, so that step must be incorrect, but I have no idea what logic you are using to write that down in the first place so I am not sure what error you are making.

Comment: I’m using abstract index notation, so $(\partial/\partial x^\mu)^a = (\partial/\partial x^\mu)$. The index $a$ is only there to denote that it’s a tensor with one contravariant slot. In that sense, I’m using $g_{ab} T^b = T_a$ with basis vectors. I assumed that going from vector to covector using the metric (ie changing index from upper to lower or the other way around) was the same as switching between the basis vector and its corresponding dual, but maybe that is wrong?

Comment: What is the title question (v2) supposed to mean? $g_{\mu \nu}$ is not always diagonal.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is the $g_{\mu \nu}$ is diagonal in flat space, and this was an attempt to prove that it is always flat?

Comment: I know that it’s not always flat. I want to know why I get to that (false) conclusion for a general basis (hence the “why does X (falsely) lead to Y?” rather than “help me prove that X leads to Y”). Obviously something is wrong in this line of reasoning, but I can’t find out what that is. I think the confusion here comes from the use of abstract index notation. I added a paragraph to clarify that. Basically, Latin indices are not components in any basis, merely symbolic.

Comment: You have to be really careful with partial derivatives. Usually you want to evaluate operator equations by acting on a test function. If you operate on a test scalar function $\phi$, then I would have written your last equation as
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\nu} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_\mu} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu}
\end{equation}
I don't understand how you got from the partial derivative $\partial_\mu$ to the one form $dx^\mu$, but there must be an error there because the index heights don't line up.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps what you intended was something like
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = g_{ab} \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x^\nu} = g_{ab} \delta^a_\mu \delta^b_\nu = g_{\mu\nu}
$$
which would represent a trivial coordinate transformation from one coordinate system to itself. (?)

Comment: $\partial / \partial x^\mu$ is a vector, ie a map from the set of smooth, real functions defined on the manifold to real numbers. Inserting it into the metric gives a covector. I think the confusion here comes from the fact that $g_{ab} \left( \partial / \partial x^\mu \right)^a$ means that the vector is inserted into the first slot of the metric tensor. This yields a map $V \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ where $V$ is the space of vectors, ie a covector.

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong! I can’t post an answer since this is closed, but thank all of you for your help (especially Andrew!)

Comment: The upper & lower indices do not match in eq. (3).

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry, I thought you were in charge of keeping the question closed, and that your reason was that I hadn’t fixed the indices. I now see that it’s still being reviewed, so please ignore my previous rant. Yeah, step (3) is where it went wrong, when replacing the basis with the dual after application with the metric. The equality simply doesn’t hold, as I’ve now come to understand. What I should’ve done was to expand the metric in the basis and then take the tensor product of everything to see what happens between basis vectors (even if doing so is a bit trivial at times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assumed that lowering an index for a basis vector yields its corresponding dual vector

This is incorrect. The metric does add a "normalization factor" to the expression. For example, consider the metric for the 2-sphere,
$$\mathrm{d}\Omega^2 = \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \mathrm{d}\phi^2.$$
Notice that
$$g_{ab}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right)^b = \sin^2\theta \left(\mathrm{d}\phi\right)_a,$$
which is necessary in order to have
$$g_{\phi\phi} = g_{ab}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right)^a\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right)^b = \sin^2\theta.$$

Of course, the case of a non-diagonal metric would also bring in mixed terms, making the expression more complicated, but I think this example suffices to show the problem. While this is enough to show that Eq. (3) is wrong, the index matching was bothering me as well. The example of Minkowski metric shows that the index should be lowered, though. Indeed,
$$\eta_{ab}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^b = - \left(\mathrm{d}t\right)_a = - \left(\mathrm{d}x^0\right)_a = \left(\mathrm{d}x_0\right)_a.$$

With these things in mind, notice that the correct computation would be
\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu} &= g_{ab}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right)^a\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}\right)^b, \\
&= g_{\mu\rho}\left(\mathrm{d} x^\rho\right)_b\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}\right)^b, \\
&= g_{\mu\rho}\delta^{\rho}{}_{\nu}, \\
&= g_{\mu\nu},
\end{align}
which is a trivial result, but what would really be surprising is if we found the components of the metric tensor without choosing the metric tensor.

Comment: It’s always beautiful how index matching can help you find where the problem is. Thank you for the well-explained answer!